# How can I reset the counter in the provided code after 7 days?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a "Coming Soon" page, but I'm having trouble understanding how to reset the counter in the provided code after 7 days. Can you please guide me on how to achieve this?

There are few other CSS and js files ,do I need to share them ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1">
        
        <title>Vistar Enterprises</title>

        <!-- Loading third party fonts -->
        <link href="fonts/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Loading main css file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/ie-support/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ie-support/respond.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>


    <body>
        
        <div class="site-content">
            
            <header class="site-header">
                <div class="container shrinked">
                    
                    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Vistar Enterprises</a></h1>
                    
                </div>  <!-- .container -->
            </header> <!-- .site-header -->

            <main class="main-content">
                <div class="container shrinked">
                    <h1 class="section-title center-aligned">We are preparing something new. <br> <span>Stay tuned!</span></h1>

                    <div class="counter-wrap" data-date-target="Dec 31, 2023 10:00:00">
                        <div class="counter days">
                            <div class="number">78</div>
                            <div class="caption">Days</div>
                        </div> <!-- .counter -->
                        <div class="counter hours">
                            <div class="number">24</div>
                            <div class="caption">Hours</div>
                        </div> <!-- .counter -->
                        <div class="counter minutes">
                            <div class="number">43</div>
                            <div class="caption">Minutes</div>
                        </div> <!-- .counter -->
                        <div class="counter seconds">
                            <div class="number">38</div>
                            <div class="caption">Seconds</div>
                        </div> <!-- .counter -->
                    </div> <!-- .counter-wrap -->

                </div>  <!-- .container -->
            </main> <!-- .main-content -->

            <footer class="site-footer">
                <div class="container shrinked">
                    
                    <p class="contact">For inquiries, contact us at:</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> mike@vistarenterprises.com</p>
                    <br>
                    
                    
                    <div class="social-links">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                    </div> <!-- .social-links -->

                    <div class="colophon">Copyright 2023 Vistar Enterprises. All right reserved</div>

                </div>  <!-- .container -->
            </footer> <!-- .site-footer -->

        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: the counter appears to be just html. What do you want to reset?

Comment: Your counter is run by your `/js/app.js` file and the inline code is invalid you cannot have dashes in JS variables. `var data-date-target="June 2, 2023 10:00:00"
    var data-date-target = new Date();
    data-date-target.setDate(data-date-target.getDate() + 7);
    data-date-target.setHours(10);
    data-date-target.setMinutes(0);
    data-date-target.setSeconds(0);`

Comment: @mplungjan ,Yes it run by js , following is js code https://pastebin.com/3ivExURM

Comment: If you click [edit] and then scroll down and click edit above snippet, you can add the JS and the RELEVANT css to the snippet. The `WOW` in your app.js is not relevant also your jQuery version is ancient

Answer (score 1):

1. Your inline code is invalid, vars cannot have `-` in them
2. Your app.js which is running the clock does not read what you try to set since it is an IIFE, Immediately Invoked Function Expression so it runs and cannot be changed.

Here is code that can be changed

To reset, do

```
clearInterval(tId)
var target_date = new Date("2023-06-10T10:00:00").getTime(); // change this date
setCountDown(target_date);
```

```js
let tId; 
function setCountDown(target_date) {
  // set the date we're counting down to
  // variables for time units
  var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
  // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
    if (current_date < target_date) {
      // do some time calculations
      days = (parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) < 10) ? "0" + parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) : parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
      seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

      hours = (parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) < 10) ? "0" + parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) : parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
      seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

      minutes = (parseInt(seconds_left / 60) < 10) ? "0" + parseInt(seconds_left / 60) : parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
      seconds = (parseInt(seconds_left % 60) < 10) ? "0" + parseInt(seconds_left % 60) : parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
    } else {
      days = '00';
      hours = '00';
      minutes = '00';
      seconds = '00';
    }
    // format countdown string + set tag value
    $(".days .number").html(days);
    $(".hours .number").html(hours);
    $(".minutes .number").html(minutes);
    $(".seconds .number").html(seconds);
  }, 1000);
}
const initTime = () => {
  var target_date = new Date("2023-06-10T10:00:00").getTime();
setCountDown(target_date);
};
$(function() { initTime() });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="main-content">
  <div class="container shrinked">
    <h1 class="section-title center-aligned">We are preparing something new. <br> <span>Stay tuned!</span></h1>

    <div class="counter-wrap">
      <div class="counter days">
        <div class="number">0</div>
        <div class="caption">Days</div>
      </div>
      <!-- .counter -->
      <div class="counter hours">
        <div class="number">0</div>
        <div class="caption">Hours</div>
      </div>
      <!-- .counter -->
      <div class="counter minutes">
        <div class="number">0</div>
        <div class="caption">Minutes</div>
      </div>
      <!-- .counter -->
      <div class="counter seconds">
        <div class="number">0</div>
        <div class="caption">Seconds</div>
      </div>
      <!-- .counter -->
    </div>
    <!-- .counter-wrap -->

  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</main>
<!-- .main-content -->
```

Comment: Thank you but I can edit the snippets . here is the js app 


https://pastebin.com/N94stYvS

HTML : https://pastebin.com/M9Gq2J9y
CSS : https://pastebin.com/xu7s7eMF

Comment: Yes you can. As I commented to your question. Why should you not be able to edit using the instructions I gave?